# MVVM notification to UI

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8

*NOTE: Please excuse my English. It ain't my native language - I sometimes misspell or use wrong time*

## SITUATION DESCRIPTION

First, I will describe the situation.

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 App ( **WP8.0** w/ **.NET 4.5** in **C#/XAML** ). This is my first WP8 App and there is not much people around me who can help me with it, so I'm learning by myself from tutorials on the net and a few books (in other words, I'm *rookie* with not so much experience).

There is "*not-so-large*" amount of data I'm gathering from a **webservices** (which I will describe later) and I decided to use **Model-View-ViewModel** (MVVM) to store the data provided by it.

### MVVM Structure:

*this is just my pseudodiagram of how the MVVM structure looks like, description is below it*

```
MainViewModel
--------------
|
+ several properties (Username, Password, etc...)
|
+ Commands (loadData1, loadData2, flush, ...  - implementations of ICommand)
|
+ ------ PersonalInfoModel
|        -----------------
|        + several properties (name, surname, phonenumber, etc...)
|
|             
+ ------ DataGroup1Model
|        ---------------
|        +several properties
|        +ObservableCollection<Item1> (roughly 0 - 50 items)
|        +ObservableCollection<Item2> (roughly 0 - 5 items)
|        +ObservableCollection<string> (roughly 0 - 5 items)
|        
|                  Item1                         Item2
|                  -----                         -----
|                  +several properties           +several other properties
|                  
|
+ ------ DataGroup2Model (similar to previous)
...et cetera...
```

I have **MainViewModel** object containing few properties and few Commands (implementing ICommand) and also several Models, that contain other properties and observablecollections.

**The MainViewModel is not populated by data at once, but over time as the user browses the application and requests it.** Mainly because there are more webservices to gather it from - some of the data must be gathered based on user-specified criteria (like from which date to which etc.)

**I decided to create one "*persistent*"** (not sure if it's the right word) **ViewModel that will be present throughout the entire application, because I sometimes need to combine data from several models in the page**

For example I need to always display some basic userinfo in "userInfoBar" that is always present on the page + i need some information from DataGroup1Model and some from DataGroup2Model (which are populated by data from two webservices and are used in more combinations then just this one).

### Webservices

I'm using webservices to gather data to populate the viewModel. Specifically one webservice with 9 methods, not sure about how to describe it - every one method gives me data about something, which i store in the datagroupModels (sometimes two datagroupmodels, like personalinfoModel and Datagroup1Model).

**The webservices have been provided to me, i can't change them, i can only use them.**

## THE "PROBLEM"

**I'm trying to figure out a good way to give signals to my pages that something is done. For example login sequence:**

1. I have a page containing two TextBoxes which values are Binded to *MainViewModel* properties *UserName* and *Password* and a Button binded to *Command Login* in *MainViewModel*.
2. *The login Command* just fires up "*doLogin*" method, which uses the *username* and *password* properties and give it as credentials to instance of *webserviceclient* autogenerated by Visual Studio when adding the webservice and *the client* executes one of the webservice methods (asynchronous method) - for example login.
3. When this method is completed, it raises the *Completed event* associated with it and provides **Result** object in its *CompletedArguments*.
4. In the completed event i copy the data from the Result object to the viewModel.

**At this point, it would be nice to give some signal to the UI that the login task is done and it should navigate to another page.**

**How should I do it?**

**Is there some preferred way to do it?**

P.S.: If you have suggestions about something described here, I will be glad to hear them. Please also bear in mind that I'm a rookie, so i sometimes need explanation for dummies or get stuck at something basic and/or stupid.

Comment: This must be the best formatted question I've seen on SO. +1

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg Well, it took me an hour to write it down. :) But I thought that the same question I'm asking could be what someone else is trying to solve, so it's better to write it down properly in case someone else needs help too.

Comment: Agreed - this is how you ask a question, it's quite annoying when someone who is asking for help doesn't spend the right amount of time in conveying their problem. People seem to forget that us lowly mortals are not omnipresent and cannot fathom the depths of another's brain from afar...i.e. write it down or we have to guess, and if we have to guess we probably won't give you a good answer! This however, is a shining example of "what should be put in a question". Well done sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you notify the UI from the view model by just changing your data. For example, you could maintain some general “state” in a `State` property that is bound to in the UI. The UI could then display different things depending on which value that property has. You usually do that with *data triggers*. If it is less complicated, you can also just have a boolean that will tell you `IsDataLoaded` or something, i.e. if you loaded the data from the web service already. Or even simpler, if you want to display the result in the view, you would just have a property `Result` which you bind to. As long as you haven’t loaded the data, the value is null and the view would display the login form. If the data is not null (i.e. data was loaded) it will just show the data instead.

As for navigation, usually you would have own view models for every page of the navigation. So if you start with a login screen, you would have a “login view model”, and if the next page is a data visualization, you would have a “data view model”. Usually this is done using data templates. Data templates are templates that are dependant on a type. You would have a “meta” view model which basically just has a slot for the currently displayed view model. And then for each possible type, you would define a data template that defines its view for the specific view model type. And then to navigate, all you do is change the current view model in the meta view model.

Comment: That's where my mind was telling me to go, although i was not sure about it. I have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented, so I can use it (plus i already have the `IsDataLoaded` property in the viewModel, maybe what I'm thinking about is creating an `event` and in the UI registering it, so when the login is completed i would just raise the event and the UI would navigate to another page without concerning myself with all the situations when IsDataLoaded might change). Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Well, you could use an event, but often people avoid specifying the exact type of the view model in the view too (note that in general, coupling the view to the view model is okay, while the reverse is not). Often, you just create some one-purpose properties that will notify the view indirectly then.

Comment: That is what i know, I want to let my view know that the viewmodel has changed and since it is dependent on a result of an asynchronous operation handled in viewmodel, i need some better way then raising propertychanged event handler with the name of the property that has changed, the best in my opinion being to raise an event telling me that this specific operation is completed when the async operation is done, and logically handling that event in view, because the view is responsible for navigation, the viewmodel is only providing means of notification that the dataloading is completed.

Answer (score 2):

If the notification needs to to the same view / viewmodel the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged to get notifications should be sufficient. 
So typically you would be updating a Success Property which in turn is also invoking the property changed event.

Alternatively if this login notification needs to travel across modules. To get the state to say a notification to a different modules (modules that are not know at the time of implementation). A publish subscribe model could be used. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx shows how to use MVVM Ligths publish mechanism.

Prisms EventAggregator could also be explored.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take a look at prism  http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/
This allow you to publish events or aggregate commands all over your app and to easily switch beetween views.
You'll have to read quite a lot documentation but this is worthwhile, I couldn't imagine develop  a strong mvvm app without it now