# Update data in MVVM periodically and automatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

In my Model and ViewModel for XAML View (List), I have a String property.
The data are retrieved in `LoadData` from a WebService.
I don't use MVVMlight.

Model:

```
public class LocationsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _id;
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewSurroundingModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewSurroundingModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<LocationsModel>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<LocationsModel> Items { get; set; }

    private string _name = "";
    private string _id = "";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _id)
            {
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public async Task<bool> LoadData()
    {
        // WEB-API CALL IS HERE...
        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
        return true;
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to update the Name property periodically by code (not re-retrieving data from WebService) every 5 minutes.

How and where can I implement this?

Comment: Where is the string property declared, in the ViewModel or the Model? Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the class that declared the string property and if so, is the PropertyChanged event raised after setting value of the property?

Comment: erm. `this.MyStringProperty = "NewString";` ?

Comment: can you show us the structure of your models/viewmodel so we can have an idea of what you want? How it looks? (for example something like [the diagram in this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377191/mvvm-notification-to-ui))

Comment: And please make some time and specify your situation, show some code etc. this question is vague and unclear. It usually means that it will not attract much attention and it will take longer to find a good answer.

Comment: Updated question with code. What I´m searching for is written in the last line: How can I implement such a "scheduler" and where should it be placed. I think, because I used `INotifyPropertyChanged` the rest would be simple for me.

Comment: Why do you want the update periodically and not just when it changes? MVVM is thought for push, not pull.

Comment: The data never changes on server. I want/must do this on the device.

Comment: If it does not change, you do not need an update... ?!?

Comment: i'm writing a quick answer. don't have much time so it won't be detailed.

Comment: I must update all entries of the list on device periodically. Server just gives me an initial list. My device must do some jobs with the entries and when finished, sending the result list to another server.

Comment: Ahh :) That's the important bit of info. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry for vague answer, don't have much time so if anyone else cares to write more about what I said, they are welcome to it.*

**How to**

One of the possibilities is using `DispatcherTimer` (more about it [for example here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Implement_timers_in_Windows_Phone)) and using it's `Tick` event.(there is a tutorial in the link provided)

**Now about where to create your timer.**

It depends on what you want to change and when you want to start it.

If I'd like to change ALL of the data in the list some predefined way, i can do it like this:

```
 public class MainViewSurroundingModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
      //...omitted the parts you have done, only writing the things I'd change...
      MainViewSurroundingModel()
      {
           ..if there was something leave it here..
           changeTimer = new DispatcherTimer...
           changeTimer.Tick += Tick;
           changeTimer.Interval = ....et cetera, setting the timer based on tutorial
      }

      public ObservableCollection<LocationsModel> items;
      public ObservableCollection<LocationsModel> Items 
      {
        get //edited so that I can write my own setter
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value != items)
            {
               items = value;
               //NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); //can be used here, not necessary
               changeTimer.Start();
            }
        }
      }

      private DispatcherTimer changeTimer;//based on the tutorial
      //based on the tutorial provided, create dispatcher timer and
      //tick definition somewhere around here

      private Tick(...)
      {
          //code that iterates through the list and updates it goes here!
      }

 }
```